# Llamar un archivo xlsx variable por el nombre de usuario

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando en un scripts php en el que he implementado la lectura de datos excel, cuando cada usuario se loguea quiero llamar al archivo excel que corresponde al cliente pero no en cuento la fórmula, la línea en la que llamo al archivo es esta:

`$archivo = "uploads/<?php echo $usename; ?>.xlsx";`

Pero no se muy bien que estoy haciendo mal, agradeceria mucho la ayuda

Comment: Agrega el respectivo [ejemplo-minimo-verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ya que con lo que pones, ya tienes una respuesta. Ademas indica a que te refieres con "No me funciona"

Answer (score 1):

Solo se necesita abrir *"tag PHP" (`eg: <?php`)* cuando aún no lo has abierto.
A simple vista, ya estas dentro de un tag PHP, de lo contrario no podrías crear la variable `$archivo`.

#### Solución:

Lo que necesitas hacer se llama "concatenar" y podes hacerlo así:

```
<?php

// ... código anterior ...

// Concatenar cadenas
$archivo = "uploads/" . $usename . ".xlsx";

// O si estas usando comillas dobles, imprimir dentro de cadenas
$archivo = "uploads/$usename.xlsx";
```

---

Referencias:

- [Operadores para strings](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.string.php)
- [Cadenas de caracteres (Strings)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, tiene sentido lo que me dices, pero aun asi no me funciona ):

Comment: @itseo se necesita mas detalles de tu pregunta, a que te refieres con "No me funciona" ¿Sale algun error?

Comment: @itseo, ¿podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar mas código? Solo las partes relevantes a la pregunta. A modo ilustrativo te dejo [esta demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/666dbb0e4f3d1d6f88634119a849c39b2cb47fd3)

Comment: @Marcos exacto, se necesita un [ejemplo-minimo-verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Buenos días, no me canta ningun error, solo no carga nada, este el código que estoy usando    <?php
          require_once 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
          $archivo = "uploads/$usename.xlsx";
          $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($archivo);
          $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
          $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($archivo);
          $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
          $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
          $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
          ?>

Comment: @itseo, parece que te estaría faltando definir la variable `$usename`, o por lo menos no se la ve en el fragmento que compartis. **PD: esta info deberías agregarla en tu pregunta**

Comment: He subido todo el codigo para que lo puedas ver completo http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9b46a34c736d2a6c2b03be1d6b45aa5badac5d58

Comment: @itseo, por las dudas no te hayas percatado, ahora el problema que tenes es OTRO, que nada tiene que ver con la pregunta. Así y todo, viendo tu código... la verdad que es difícil saber porque no te funciona. ¿Verificaste que la ruta al archivo se correcta? ¿Verificaste que el archivo exista? ([`is_file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-file.php))